# Setting table count to variable in shell script..?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, variables, ingres

I'm looking to return a numeric value within the "count" variable from my SQL I wrote. Unfortunately I am just getting an Ingres error message. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

See shell script code below:

```
#!/bin/ksh
###############

count=$(sql db_name -s -N "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_table;")

echo "Table count = $count"
```

See Ingres error below:

```
Table count = INGRES TERMINAL MONITOR Copyright 2008 Ingres Corporation 
E_US0022 Either the flag format or one of the flags is incorrect,
    or the parameters are not in proper order.
```

Expected outcome:

```
Table count = 8
```

Comment: If you are using the Korn shell, use the `ksh` tag, not the `bash` tag. Regardless, this isn't a shell issue; there's a problem with your SQL command.

Comment: Have you tried executing `sql db_name -s -N "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_table;"` to see what the output is outside your script?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=>|Fri Feb 17|01:51:01|postgres@[STATION]:/var/lib/pgsql> ./test.sh
count ------- 3 (1 row)

=>|Fri Feb 17|01:51:04|postgres@[STATION]:/var/lib/pgsql> cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

count=$(psql <<EOF
select count(*) from mdn_2 ;
EOF
)
# Prints the result captured from DB
echo $count

=>|Fri Feb 17|01:51:05|postgres@[STATION]:/var/lib/pgsql>
```

Comment: Result is now: 

"INGRES TERMINAL MONITOR Copyright 2008 Ingres Corporation Ingres SPARC SOLARIS Version II 9.2.1 login Thu Apr 20 11:30:40 2017 continue Executing . . . +-------------+ |col1 | +-------------+ | 8| +-------------+ (1 row) Your SQL statement(s) have been committed. Ingres Version II 9.2.1 logout Thu Apr 20 11:30:40 2017"

Any idea's how I can just return "8"?

Comment: Possible for you to share the screenshot here? I can then check and respond.

Answer (score 1):

-N isn't a valid flag for the Ingres terminal monitor (sql command).
You probaby want something like this (in bash):

```
count=`echo "select count(*) from iitables;\g" | sql -S iidbdb`
```

For more info on the flags accepted, see the documentation: 
http://docs.actian.com/#page/Ing_CommandRef%2FCommandRef_Body.1.235.htm%23